# Basket analysis with redundant items

Tags: market-basket-analysis

Assume I want to do a basket analysis on 1.000.000 baskets. Assume that 99% of them bought milk, for some reason, how can we cope with that, since (almost) all baskets have `item -> milk`.

When doing NLP you can specify "stop-words" like "the","and" etc., can you do that aswell here, simply by saying that items that occur in more then e.g 70% of the baskets should be removed or.. ?